# what is the difference between a node and a Subject Node as in HP ALM\QC

Tags: hp-quality-center, alm

what is the difference between  a node and a Subject Node in HP-ALM\QC
I know that Both appear same , but cannot be used in the same way.
Tried a lot of googling but of no use. Also check the OTA document but could not get better understanding. Can any one help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? This is a we-help-you-get-your-code-running site, not an open question forum. Connect you question to a practical example, and we´ll see.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between the ISysTreeNode and ISubjectNode interfaces? ISubjectNode derives from ISysTreeNode and adds access to the test factory. Maybe there are other trees for which ISysTreeNode is appropriate. But ISubjectNode is certainly useful for navigating the Subject tree.